# Handling multiple requests in Flask

Tags: python, flask

My Flask applications has to do quite a large calculation to fetch a certain page. While Flask is doing that function, another user cannot access the website, because Flask is busy with the large calculation.

Is there any way that I can make my Flask application accept requests from multiple users?

Comment: to offload large calculations you could use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html). It can use multiple processes, threads, microthreads to execute tasks.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes, deploy your application on a different WSGI server, see the [Flask deployment options documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/).

The server component that comes with Flask is really only meant for when you are developing your application; even though it can be configured to handle concurrent requests with `app.run(threaded=True)` (as of Flask 1.0 this is the default). The above document lists several options for servers that can handle concurrent requests *and* are far more robust and tuneable.

Comment: will use my chance to ask here in comments - which way would you suggest from those 5 listed in documentation?

Comment: @IgnasB.: Sorry, that depends heavily on your use-cases, experience and deployment scenarios. I cannot say I have used all 5 either, so I am not going to make a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, it works!
I have only one (quite important) problem left: If the user accesses the page, but leaves before the calculation is done, the calculation just keeps running until it's done.

How can I make the calculation stop running if the user leaves?

Comment: @Neyuh: Not sure you can do much about that, actually. It could be that flask raises an exception if the socket is closed early, not certain.

Comment: Thank you so much for the threaded=True hint. :) I've wasted hours searching for an explanation why concurrent file uploads made my flask app choke.

Comment: Just being curious @MartijnPieters, I've read everywhere "don't use the internal dev server because it's bad (insecure + slow)", have you seen a benchmark showing that it's really much slower than wsgi+apache, and if so, by which factor? Also have you seen a security problem in it? Having such a source would be helpful to understand the real need to set up a more complex architecture (flask + gunicorn + wsgi + apache instead of just flask), etc. Thanks in advance if you have these informations.

Comment: @Basj: No, but that's because I haven't looked for a benchmark. You shouldn't even begin to compare the built-in development server with other WSGI servers, it's like asking if the family car is suitable for a Formula 1 race. The **stated goal** of the built-in server is to make it easy for you to get up and running and start developing with minimal fuss. To that end the server is built on top of the standard-library pure-python web server. Performance and security are non-goals, while Apache and mod_wsgi (or uWSGI, or Gunicorn) very specifically focus on performance and security.

Answer (score 3):

For requests that take a long time, you might want to consider starting a background job for them.

Comment: What is a long time? Would say 10 seconds be a long time? Or is anything above a minute a long time? I guess this is application dependant, but are there any thumb rules?

Comment: You don't want your request to timeout or your users to think that it is just blocked, I think 10 seconds is already risky, anything more than that is too long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275646/how-do-i-run-background-job-in-flask-without-threading-or-task-queue