# Should I use multi threading in my flask application while running it on uwsgi?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am using a flask application running under uwsgi. Now I haven't used any processes, threads or workers in uwsgi and all I want to do is to handle concurrent requests. So shall I use multi threading in my flask application to handle concurrent requests?

p.s - I expect at least 500 requests/sec on my app.

...

//Flask Application

```
def app():

    start_thread()
```

...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple requests in Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672753/handling-multiple-requests-in-flask)

Comment: No boost or speed improvement using threads actually, use them for desing your app not looking for speed