# Access variable and render it in different URL

Tags: machine-learning, flask, web-deployment

I tried to render a variable('**predictions**') in URL(**/predict**) on url('**/hello**'). I am beginner in the web development. If someone knows , please help.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def apicall(responses = None):

    test_json = request.get_json()

    test = pd.read_json(test_json, orient='records')

    query_df = pd.DataFrame(test)

    clf = 'kmeans__model.pkl'

    print("Loading the model...")
    lin_reg_model = None
    with open(clf,'rb') as f:

        lin_reg_model = joblib.load(f)

        # lin_reg_model = joblib.load('/home/q/new_project/models/kmeans_model.pkl')

        print("The model has been loaded...doing predictions now...")

        predictions = lin_reg_model.predict(test)

        print(predictions)


        prediction_series = list(pd.Series(predictions))

        final_predictions = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(prediction_series)))

        responses = jsonify(predictions=final_predictions.to_json(orient="records"))
        responses.status_code = 200

        return (responses)

@app.route('/hello')

def hello():

  **What should be used here to render *predictions*?**  

    return 'Hello, World '
```

Comment: Do you want to run the `apicall` function when hello url execute ?

Comment: Yes, and I want to print the variable called 'predictions' too in hello url. Is it possible to render this variable in predict url?

Comment: What's stopping you to call the apicall() like function not via flask route.

Comment: Is it possible to render this variable in predict url?

Comment: Still I don't understand. After getting the prediction do you want to show in the template ?

Comment: my aim is to render this variable)) Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can return to template and show in html if you like. Create `templates` folder and create html file.

```
import requests

def hello():
    response = requests.get(url_for('apicall'))
    return render_template('<yourtemplate.html>', predictions=response.json())
```

**HTML**

```
{{ predictions }}
```

Note: Please follow this link for any problem with thread and deployment [Handling multiple requests in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672774/3762142)

Comment: the problem is that function hello does not see variable 'predictions'.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict. I've got this error "Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL"

Comment: Please add GET to methods

Comment: And also you have to add prediction variable. I thought you can call the prediction and assign to prediction variable

Comment: See my edits also please remove the app.route decorator  from apicall

Comment: How apicall will receive the json data that I send if I remove decorator app.route?

Comment: I'm so sorry @RustemKussaiynov I've been such idiot. Can you please explain to me what do you want to achive ?

Comment: My aim is to show variable called 'predictions' in url page.

Comment: Also in your example you've shown `hello` route can you tell me what is that for ?

Comment: It is for me to  check that created app is working. And I thought it is better to render variable predictions in another url

Comment: @RustemKussaiynov I understood you want to test `predictions` variable with another url but if you want to work this way you have to make the network call to your own server in this case '/predictions` and then pass this to hello html. Do you want this approach I can modify my answer for this...

Comment: I appreciate your help. Yes, It will be very good and my goal is to show this variable , no matter what is approach

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Don't know about the error. Can you please update your question with your current code

Comment: can you please give your email address?

Comment: Please ping me in twitter. My username in my SO profile