# Handling multiple client requests in flask, separately?

Tags: python, flask

I wrote the flask app which picks the random word from the text file.
User has to guess the letters in it then after winning the game Congratulation message gets printed and single user can start new game. It was working fine with single user.
Then I deployed that flask app on https://www.pythonanywhere.com (My app : https://www.flaskappsachin.pythonanywhere.com)
Whenever I open the app on different devices, at first time, flask app picks different words from that file but after winning first game now both the clients will be served with the same word. In addition to that after first winning now if one user guesses before other then both users will be shown with the victory message.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This would be a similar issue, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672753/handling-multiple-requests-in-flask

Comment: Tried that and that ain't working!!!!!

Comment: It worked. Thank You.